# Falling to configure Test::DBIx::Class::Schema for a Dancer2 to app

Tags: perl, dbix-class, dancer

I,m trying to run a sanity test for my `Dancer2` app schema using `Test::DBIx::Class::Schema.` 
I created a  `test.t`  and placed in my main app directory (not inside the `/t` folder). The file  looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Test::More  'no_plan';
use Test::DBIx::Class::Schema;
use Dancer2::Test app => ['PearlBee'];
use lib 'lib';
use lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema;

use strict;
use warnings;

# the order is important


BEGIN { 
    use_ok 'Test::DBIx::Class::Schema';
    #use_ok 'lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema';
    use_ok 'Dancer2::Test', app => 'PearlBee';
    use_ok 'lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema';# apps => ['PearlBee'];

    #
    #use_ok 'DBICx::TestDatabase';
}

#my $schema = DBICx::TestDatabase->new('lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema');


my $schematest = Test::DBIx::Class::Schema->new(
    {
        # required
        dsn       => 'dbi:mysql:PearlBee;host=localhost;', # or use schema option
        namespace  => 'lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema',
        moniker   => 'user',
        # optional
        username  => 'root',
        password  => '1',
        glue      => 'Result',
        #test_missing => 1,
    }
);

$schematest->methods(
        {
            columns => [
                qw[
                    id
                    salt

                ]
            ],

             resultsets => [
            qw[ User
            ]
        ],
        }
    );

 $schematest->run_tests();
```

I crashes with the following output:

```
Can't locate object method "connect" via package "lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema"
```

Please help me to make sense out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines look interesting:

```
use lib 'lib';
use lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema;
```

The first one seems ok. I can see why you'd want to add 'lib' to `@INC`. But having done that, I'd expect the second line to be:

```
use PearlBee::Model::Schema;
```

It seems very unlikely that you'd need that `lib::` on the front of the module name. But perhaps your directory structure is more complex that I'm assuming. Where is the PearlBee schema module?

**Update:** Also note that the latest version of the [Dancer2::Test documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Test#DESCRIPTION) says this:

> **DEPRECATED.** Please use [Plack::Test](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Test) instead as shown in the SYNOPSIS!
>
> This module will warn for a while until we actually remove it. This is
>   to provide enough time to fully remove it from your system.

I suggest you follow that advice.

Comment: Same thing also in the `$schematest` setup: `namespace  => 'lib::PearlBee::Model::Schema',` ... this `lib::` is also wrong.